# Generate an array for SoapClient call in PHP 7

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap, call

I have this xml call which working well in soap ui.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <globalSearch xmlns="http://v4.websvc.customer.com/">
            <arg0 xsi:type="ns1:searchCriteriaDTO" xmlns=""
                xmlns:ns1="http://v4.websvc.customer.com/">
                <name xsi:type="xsd:string">bouwy</name>
                <firstName xsi:type="xsd:string"></firstName>
                <postalCode xsi:type="xsd:string"></postalCode>
                <cityOrProvince xsi:type="xsd:string">lens</cityOrProvince>
                <country xsi:type="xsd:string">UA</country>
                <buNumber xsi:type="xsd:int">023</buNumber>
                <maxNumberOfResults xsi:type="xsd:int">30
                </maxNumberOfResults>
                <detailedSearch xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</detailedSearch>
                <deletedAlso xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</deletedAlso>
            </arg0>
    </globalSearch>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I don't understand how to build an array in php to male a call:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$data = $soap->globalSearch($params);
```

in $params should be an array in this specific format.

I tried this, but got the response from the server "Fault occurred while processing"

```
$params = array (
    'arg0' => array (
     'name' => 'bouwy',
     'firstName' => '',
     'postalCode' => '',
     'cityOrProvince' => 'lens',
     'country' => 'UA',
     'buNumber' => '023',
     'maxNumberOfResults ' => '30',
     'detailedSearch ' => 'true',
     'deletedAlso' => 'false'
     )
    );
```

Help, please

Comment: Is 'Fault occured while processing' the only message you get? What does the SoapFault object say? Are exceptions and trace in the options array of the soap client enabled? How does your last request look like? Try to output it with `echo htmlentities($soap->__getLastRequest())` when trace is enabled.

Comment: What data type does the WSDL define for `searchCriteriaDTO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fix the array and it works

```
$params = array (
'arg0' => array (
'searchCriteriaDTO' => '',
 'name' => 'bouwy',
 'firstName' => '',
 'postalCode' => '',
 'cityOrProvince' => 'lens',
 'country' => 'UA',
 'buNumber' => '023',
 'maxNumberOfResults ' => '30',
 'detailedSearch ' => 'true',
 'deletedAlso' => 'false',
 'any' => ''
 )
);
```

Thanks to all